# SQL Server Trigger on a Linked Server for reporting services

Tags: sql-server, triggers, linked-server

I have and SQL server with a report table that is linked to an SQL database on a separate server.  The linked server is maintained by a 3rd party vendor so I'd rather not add triggers...  I was hoping to run a report based on a value being inserted on a linked table. Tried the following:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RunReport] ON [linkedServer].[database].[dbo].
  [CustomerComments]
  FOR INSERT
  AS 
  exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', 
  @EventData='xxxxx'
```

I get the error "contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2."  Anyway to trigger my report without altering the linked database.  I also created a view of the linked table that didn't work either.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are using full SQL Server (not express), you can create a job that will check frequently if there are new records in your linked table.

Comment: Creating a trigger on a table on a linked server that executes an SSRS report sounds like a really terrible idea.

Comment: Putting a trigger on a table in a different database seems like a flawed concept.  What do you expect to happen when that table gets maintained on their end?  Did you want your trigger to pick up those changes?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the idea, you can create the trigger on linked server this way:

```
exec [linkedServer].[database].sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RunReport] ON [dbo].
  [CustomerComments]
  FOR INSERT
  AS 
  exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', 
  @EventData='xxxxx'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to all this.  Is this bad practice?  Should I just add SSRS to the actual Server or link the SSRS server to the server with the actual table?

Comment: Trigger is a part of you transaction, think what can happen if your report server is unavailable for some reason. Maybe you should use Service Broker to send a message and another server (that is not Express)  can process it? At least your transaction will succeed independently of message processing that is asyncronous